# get scroll y position doesn't work in my case

Tags: javascript, scroll

```
        var get_scroll = function(){
    y = 0;
  if( document.body && ( document.body.scrollTop ) ) {

        y = document.body.scrollTop;
    }

    return y;
};
```

It always return 0, what's wrong in above code?

I do `console.log(get_scroll());`

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if you have  declared, the scrolling position of the document is accessed differently. Without a doctype,i.e., quirks mode, the position is universally retrieved as:

```
document.body.scrollTop;
```

In standard mode, this is a bit tricky. For both IE and Firefox the following code will do:

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

However, Webkit based browsers such as Chrome still populate the body.scrollTop value. So you'll have to pick the greater two:

```
function get_scroll(){
    var top=document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (top<document.body.scrollTop) top=document.body.scrollTop;
    return top;
}
```

Isn't it ironic how quirks mode sometimes works more "standard" than the standard mode?

Comment: I even tried console.log(window.scrollY); it gave me zero too. I scroll and fire it, why it returned a zero?

Comment: Oh this is not for IE. Browsers have different rendering modes. I have modified the answer to fit your function call.

Comment: You may use the developer tool that's part of your browser to see which DOM object is populated. try document.body.scrollTop and document.documentElement.scrollTop. See which one returns higher value. The condition statement in your original question was necessary to detect if the attribute value is present. Again, different rendering mode (having a doctype vs. not) will populate the DOM structure differently.

Comment: I found out it was                         '-webkit-overflow-scrolling': 'touch'
broke the thing.

Comment: heh. well now you know :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the if condition, but without it, I got successful results (using Chrome):

```
var get_scroll = function(){
  y = document.body.scrollTop;
  return y;
}

console.log(get_scroll());
```

Answer (score 0):

Double Check this:

```
if( document.body && ( document.body.scrollTop ) )
```

It doesn't make any sense to me. document.body won't return a true/false value, and neither will document.body.scrollTop. Try changing it to a comparison of two like values. If you set it to:

```
var get_scroll = function(){
  y = 0;
  if( 1==1 ) {
     y = document.body.scrollTop;
  }
  return y;
};
```

It should work.